# Securing Credit Card numbers in python using RE

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to mask a credit card number by masking the middle 4 digits with a star. I'm trying to figure this out using RE in python.

```
5415********4935
```

While i have figured out how to do the above. the output provides me with a series of credit card numbers without any commas

```
['5415********4935\r\n5275********9664\r\n5206********3509\r\n5332********3074\r\n5204********2617']
```

Where do i need to change the code so that i get the below output

```
['5415********4935,5275********9664,5206********3509,5332********3074,5204********2617']
```

My sample code:

```
import re,pyperclip

CreditRegex = re.compile(r'''(
(\d{4})
(\s*|\-*)
(\d{4})
(\s*|\-*)
(\d{4})
(\s*|\-*)
(\d{4})

)''',re.VERBOSE)

text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches=[]

for groups in [CreditRegex.sub(r'\2********\8',text)]:

    groups.rstrip()
    matches.append(groups)

print(matches)
```

Comment: Do you really want this to be a list with one element? Or you wanted a list of strings - every credit card number as a separate element in the list? Take a look on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way using replace:

```
x = ['5415********4935\r\n5275********9664\r\n5206********3509\r\n5332********3074\r\n5204********2617']
x[0] = x[0].replace("\r\n",',')
print x
#prints ['5415********4935,5275********9664,5206********3509,5332********3074,5204********2617']
```

Comment: Was there something wrong in the code which prevented it from doing the above automatically?

Comment: Depends on how `text` looks like

Comment: I really doubt that the desired outcome was to get a list with one element which is string containing all the numbers separated with commas...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) function

```
>>> lst = ['5415********4935\r\n5275********9664\r\n5206********3509\r\n5332********3074\r\n5204********2617']

>>> [ lst[0].replace('\r\n', ',') ]
['5415********4935,5275********9664,5206********3509,5332********3074,5204********2617']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re,pyperclip

CreditRegex = re.compile(r'''(
(\d{4})
(\s*|\-*)
(\d{4})
(\s*|\-*)
(\d{4})
(\s*|\-*)
(\d{4})

)''',re.VERBOSE)

text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches=[]

for groups in [CreditRegex.sub(r'\2********\8',text)]:

    groups.rstrip()
    matches.append(groups)

print matches
```

remove () from print.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the need of regular expression here.

```
import pyperclip

out = [
    '{}********{}'.format(num[:4], num[8:])
    for num in str(pyperclip.paste()).splitlines()
]
print out
```

As you can see, all you need are standard string operations.
I find it convenient here to use the list comprehension but that's a different story.

Comment: This is way easier. Thanks for this. The reason why i was using regex is because this was one on the problems in automatetheboringstuff.com :)